# Automation through Python

Tags: python-3.x

I am new to Python and but simultaneously I try to code as well. I am stuck in a situation where I need help. I have written few code lines for launching an application. I want to run the code minimum 2 times for getting the proper output and to compare the results of the 2 runs. When I am trying to run the code, it is executing it for only one time and giving me the output for only one run of code. I have tried For loop as well but still the same output.

Running the code on pycharm:

```
import subprocess

import os

os.chdir(r"C:\Program Files\xxx")

subprocess.Popen(r"C:\Program Files\xxx\xxx")

os.system('cmd /k "xx b"')
```

After applying for loop:

import subprocess

import os

os.chdir(r"C:\Program Files\xxx")

## define here the number of times you want to run your program

total_no_run=2

for i in range(total_no_run):

```
 subprocess.Popen(r"C:\Program Files\xx\xx.exe")

 os.system('cmd /k "xx b"')
```

I want to run the above code for 2 times but I am failing to achieve it. It is running only for one time and giving me the output

Comment: A for loop is indeed the simple obvious solution, so please edit your question to add the looped version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is what you're asking for?

```
import subprocess

import os

from concurrent.futures import  ThreadPoolExecutor


def sevenZip():
    os.chdir(r"C:\Program Files\7-Zip")
    subprocess.Popen(r"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe")
    os.system('cmd /k "7z b"')

with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=2) as e:
    e.submit(sevenZip)
    e.submit(sevenZip)
```

Comment: i tried using this as well but the problem is the code is getting executed only one time and giving me the output but for the next run it is not working at all.

Comment: Just editted it. takes a little while to benchmark it but i get 2 benchmarks at the end